# VBA what is more optimal: filtering hidden rows

Tags: vba, excel

I need to filter a excel sheet with more than 50000 rows 512 times. I am currently using the following code.

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.value)

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        filtro = ActiveCell.value

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("D1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$" & lastRow("D")).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=filtro

        Range("A1").Select

        Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.value)

            Do

                ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
                oProgress.Increase 1

            Loop While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

                Call functio ' this function do something with the actual row

        Loop

    Loop
```

The problem is it's taking so much time to analyse 50000 rows X 512 times!, I was thinking maybe it is better to filter and then copy the rows into a temporary sheet, and check the values there?.

The line Active is processed by the function readValues

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, there are a few ways more efficient than this. Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: Yes Il will update my main post

Comment: You need to post all the code, ie the bit that comes before and whatever is in readValues

Comment: Yes, and if you explain this `filter a sheet .. 512 times`. Do you really need to filter for 512 different values? Are you trying to get a count of values or a sum of something? If you can be more specific in what you are doing it will help - along with posting code.

Comment: Yes I need because I have to create UMTS codes and I have to create one array witch any of this codes for that reason i have to filter, now im updated my main post sorry for not be so clear im working in that for help me and more persons how has the same issue

Comment: See my answer below, Jonathan.

Comment: There is no such thing as more optimal!

Comment: Can you post the code for what your "Call functio" does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like other posters to this question, I really am skeptical about filtering `512` times! However, since you say you absolutely need it, see this code below. I think it could be cleaned up still based on your needs, but its hard to say without seeing the bigger scope. It should however take you to a more efficient place than were you are now.

I tried to comment all my assumptions, but please reach out if you need more explanation.

```
Sub FilterAll512()

Dim wks1 As Worksheet
Set wks1 = Sheets(1)

Dim rng512 As Range, cel As Range
Set rng512 = wks1.Range("A1:A512") '-> say your filter values are in this range, adjust if needed

Dim wks2 As Worksheet
Set wks2 = Sheets(2)

For Each cel In rng512

    With wks2

        Dim rngFound As Range
        Set rngFound = .Columns(4).Find(cel.Text, LookIn:=xlWhole) ' -> make sure value is there to be filtered on

        If rngFound Then

                .UsedRange.AutoFilter 4, cel.Text '-> assumes upper left most cell is A1

                Dim rngSearch As Range, rngCel As Range
                '-> assumes upper left most cell is A1 and row 1 has headers
                Set rngSearch = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), .Columns(4).EntireColumn).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

                For Each rngCell In rngSearch

                    oProgress.Increase 1 '-> i don't know what this does, but it doesn't look very efficient, see notes below

                    Call functio

                Next

                '-> perhaps above you are just counting rows?
                    'if so, you can use rngSearch.Rows.Count to get a total count
                    'or you can use rngCell.Row to get the current row



        End If 'iF rngFound Then

    End With ' With wks2

Next 'For Each cel In rng512

Set rngCell = Nothing
Set rngSearch = Nothing
Set rngFound = Nothing
Set cel = Nothing
Set rng512 = Nothing
Set wks2 = Nothing
Set wk1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Whao there are some codes I dont have clear and im going to check by my own, its ok Scott If i have some time for diggest it?. And I'll back tomorow with more clear VBa words. because it looks can help me

Comment: Take your time @JonathanRaulTapiaLopez. :)

Comment: @JonathanRaulTapiaLopez -> I saw you tried to edit my post with some questions. It's best to ask your questions in a comment. Then all can benefit.

Comment: yes  sorry again for that. Im doing to much mistakes .... i wrote my question lines down

Answer (score 0):

Excel has built in filtering tools(most people would describe it as an extremely basic function of excel). And even if you did have to loop through 500,000 rows, this is quite possibly one of the the worst(slowest) and most bizarre ways you could do it:

```
Do                 
    ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select 
Loop While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

You can look into Range().Sort and Range().AutoFilter which are the correct ways to do it. Good Luck.

Comment: yes sorry I didnt put the full code, im gonna reedit the main topic with the full topic

Comment: I can't think of a practical purpose for having to filter a table 512 times and then loop through every cell(512 times). Once should be enough. So you are probably going to need to give a high level description of what you are trying to achieve. And I think there is somewhat of a language barrier here, so it might be better to post your question on a website more related to your contry of origin. Good Luck.

Comment: Ok Im going to try to explain the problem, In UMTS (3G networks) you have 512 diferentes types of codes, and Every cell in the networks has one of this codes.  What im trying to do, is filter Sheet1(contains all the full network with more that 500000 cells) with the code number "1" and create a file (KML) with all the rows for Code "1", and do the same with next 511 codes, I hope someone understandme, And sorry for my grammar it sucks

Comment: @JonathanRaulTapiaLopez - See my answer below. It should give you what you need.

Comment: Hi Jon, This is a good description and is exactly what people need to be able to answer your question. It seems like Scott has a solution posted but I would recommend putting a description like this in your future questions(you get better answers). Just from your description, this seems like a straight-forward problem. To me, it doesn't seem to require any row looping - you simply need to loop through all the codes and autofilter the table for everyone of those codes and then create your KML file for each filtered table(I am not familiar with this format but you can convert to it from a csv).

Answer (score -1):

An idea of what you can do is to calculate all row numbers or range of row numbers and then apply a code like this:

```
rowNumbers = "1:3,10:10,30:50"
Range(rowNumbers).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Comment: mm but the problem is I can calculate the rows because the filtes change my rows every time